# "Cast string to float is not supported [[node categorical_crossentropy/Cast Unimplemented: Cast string to float is not supported. "

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training 3dcnn with images along with their bounding boxes. but when I execute the program I get following error. I googled  but find nothing to fix it. any help will be appreciated.

here is the SAMPLE code:

```
    images = glob.glob("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/Images/*.ppm")
    images = sorted(images,key= os.path.getmtime)
    train_image =[]
    x1 = []
    depth = 10
    for i in tqdm(range(len(images))):
       timg = image.load_img(images[i])
       image1= timg.resize((40, 40))
      img = image.img_to_array(image1)
      train_image.append(img)   
    print(len(train_image)) 
    IMG = np.array(train_image)
    train_image = np.expand_dims(train_image,4)
    x = train_image.transpose(4,0,1,2,3)
    print("shape of x,",x.shape)
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/data_js1.csv')  
    Y_In = np.array(df)
    Y_In = Y_In.reshape(1,-1)
    Input_shape1 =(40,40,40,3) 
    num_classes = 1
    model = Sequential()  
    X_train = x
    Y_train = Y_In
    print(Y_train.shape,"y_train shape")    
    print(X_train.shape,"x shape") 
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), input_shape = 
    Input_shape1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool size=(2,2,2)))                    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Batch Normalization())
```

Comment: model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy,optimizer='Adam',metrics=['accuracy']) print(model.summary()) history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=40, epochs=3, verbose=1, shuffle=True)

Comment: Does the dataframe just contain the bounding boxes? Also why are you applying batch normalization on the last layer?

Comment: this is some part of the code.. last layer is not actually batch normalization. its dense. yes just contain bounding boxes. [[71.78683385579937, 72.01253918495298], [111.5987460815047, 251.94984326018812]] here is the value from one cell of csv

Comment: Could you find the type of these values in your dataframe? It seems that there are strings.

Comment: these are object datatype

Comment: Try converting the column with the bounding boxes to floats using `df["bounding_boxes"] = pd.to_numeric(df.bounding_boxes, errors='coerce')`